# Grouping rows to minimise deviation

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, statistics

I have a Employee Wages table like this, with their EmpID and their wages.

```
  EmpId   | Wages
  ================
    101   | 1280
    102   | 1600
    103   | 1400
    104   | 1401
    105   | 1430
    106   | 1300
```

I need to write a **Stored Procedure** in **SQL Server**, to group the Employees according to their wages, such that similar salaried people are in groups together and the deviations within the group is as minimum as possible.

There are no other conditions or rules mentioned.

The output should look like this

```
  EmpId   | Wages | Group
  =======================
    101   | 1280  |  1
    106   | 1300  |  1
    103   | 1400  |  2
    104   | 1401  |  2
    105   | 1430  |  2
    102   | 1600  |  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT EmpId, Wages, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(Wages - t.min_wage AS INT) / 100) AS grp
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(Wages) AS min_wage FROM mytable) AS t
```

The query calculates the distance of each wage from the minimum wage and then uses *integer division* by `100` in order to place records in slices. So all records that have a deviation that is between `0 - 99` off the minimum wage are placed in the first slice. The second slice contains records off by `100 - 199` from the minimum wage, etc.

Comment: So, you are basically scaling down and comparing.
But what if after scaling down, the scaled wages come to be 98 and 101. ideally they too should be in the same group.

Comment: @CodeFearer Yes this is a shortcoming of my query. But you may have similar issues with any other method selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can for `+-30 deviation` as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (EmpId INT, Wages INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES  
(99, 99),
(100, 101),
(101, 1280),
(102, 1600),
(103, 1400),
(104, 1401),
(105, 1430),
(106, 1300)

;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Wages) AS RowId FROM @Tbl )

SELECT 
    A.EmpId ,
    A.Wages ,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(B.RowId)) [Group]
FROM 
    CTE A CROSS JOIN CTE B
WHERE 
    ABS(B.Wages - A.Wages) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 -- Here +-30
GROUP BY A.EmpId, A.Wages
ORDER BY A.Wages
```

Result:

```
EmpId       Wages       Group
----------- ----------- --------------------
99          99          1
100         101         1
101         1280        2
106         1300        2
103         1400        3
104         1401        3
105         1430        3
102         1600        4
```